# How to delete pipeline job through mail approval in groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to write groovy script which should send an email notification to the approver for deleting a pipeline job in Jenkins.

I am able to send email and get the approvers input, but I am confused on how to retrieve the input(Proceed or Abort).If input is Proceed, I should delete the job and if it is Abort, job shouldn't be deleted.

I looked at some reference and used "approveReceivedEvent" , but it is not working. Is there any way for retrieving user input?

Below is my code snippet

```html
stage ('DELETE')
  build job: 'JOBNAME', wait: true
  mail to: 'xxx@xxx', subject: "Please approve #${env.JOB_NAME} to delete", 
  body: <p>Job '${env.JOB_NAME}" + environment + "[${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]' NEEDS APPROVAL</p><p>Please approve at &QUOT;<a href='${env.JOB_URL}'>${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]</a>&QUOT;</p>"

  try {
        input id: 'Proceed', message: "\nDo you want to proceed to delete job?"
    } catch (err) {
        //approveReceivedEvent(id: id, approved: false)
        throw err
      }
    //approveReceivedEvent(id: id, approved: true)
    }
    job(env.JOB_NAME) {
      steps {
        dsl {
          removeAction('DELETE')
        }
      }
}
```

Modified the code.Below is the code snippet which worked.

```html
 def userInput =  input (message: 'Approve Delete', submitterParameter: 'isApproved')
 
     echo ("userInput was: " + userInput)

     if(userInput.equals("Yes"))
     {
      job(env.JOB_NAME) {
         steps {
           dsl {
              removeAction('DELETE')
            }
          }
   }
     }
     else
     {
      echo("No Approval received to delete Job")
     }
```

Comment: what is the `job` step?

Comment: An `input` step will continue, if the user clicked OK or abort the build otherwise. So I'm not sure, why you want those `approveReceivedEvent`s.

Comment: Yeah I got it resolved with input step.Thanks

Comment: Please post your code so that others can benefit from it.

Comment: added code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can try is , make a separate job (lets call it 'J') with the above mentioned code snippet and make it have the same parameters as input which are required by your code like :

`JOB_NAME , BUILD_NUMBER , APPROVED` etc.

Now in your original job when you send the mail you can give links for APPROVED = YES or 1 and APPROVED = NO or 0 . In those links you can remotely trigger your job 'J' with the parameters you sent in the mail and APPROVED parameter as 1 or 0 for the two links .